# Geometry Nodes: How to make jagged/stepped line (mesh or curve)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to make this Version Control or GIT style branching with geometry nodes, so that the branch starting points and ending points were in random places of the line (but still not right next to each other or overlapping):

[image]

I guess the first logical step is to make some 'Mesh line' components with some amount of increments (... and then something ...) and then convert those to curves and use 'Curve fillet' to make the curves round.

But how to make those randomly jagged lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yess, found a better way!
Somewhat complicated, but works.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way to get really close is to use shortest edge path on a grid:
[image]

[image]